# Notification Permission is granting automaticlly in android java

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

i am creating a temp app which request Notification permission to android. But Notification permission is getting granted automatically without prompting or doing something.
Do you have any idea? about this.

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Temp"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

java file

```
package com.example.temp;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(v -> requestNotificationPermission());

}


public void requestNotificationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

build.gradle file

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
namespace 'com.example.temp'
compileSdk 33

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.temp"
    minSdk 24
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

I am not able to figueout why this is happening and my target device has latest android version.

Answer (score 1):

The permission you are trying to use [android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission) is relatively new. It works for Android 13 and above.

Android had no permission for push notifications earlier. By default it is granted to the app and can be turned off by the user.

So you should keep in mind:

1. No permission on Android < 13 at the moment
2. To use the permission you should build the app with Android 13 (or upper). Check your compile, build and target versions.

Comment: For Android < 13, if it is turned off by user, can we detect and request for user to allow permission on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use android compileSdkVersion 33 in your build.gradle file. Then you'll be allowed to use the POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission without any issue.

In my case, 
compileSdkVersion 33
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
targetSdkVersion 33

Hope this will helpful for you.

Comment: I have udpated the same question, with build.gradle file content. Can you please check whether is it correct one?

Comment: build.gradle (Module :app)